# How not to print exception on console

Tags: java, spring

I implemented my own custom exception. I do not want it to print the exception on the framework console. Is it possible?

> May 15, 2017 2: 47: 24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet[project - services] in context with path[/project-services] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is ba.project.exception.TAException: There is no any tour activity between selected dates.] with root cause
>       ba.project.exception.TAException: There is no any tour activity between selected dates.at ba.project.service.TAServices.findByTourTypeWithDates(TAServices.java: 94)

Custom Exception:

```
 public class TAException extends RuntimeException {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;

  public TAException(String msg) {
    super(msg);
  }

  public TAException(String msg, Throwable e) {
    super(msg, e);
  }
}
```

Here is how I throw exception:

```
public List < Object > findByTourTypeWithDates(String tourType, Date checkin, Date checkout)
throws ParseException, TAException {
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

  Date todayDate = dateFormatter.parse(dateFormatter.format(new Date()));
  if (checkin.after(todayDate)) {
    return taDAO.findByTourTypeWithDates(tourType, checkin, checkout);
  }
  throw new TAException("There is no any tour activity between selected dates.");
}
```

Comment: What did you expect? If you throw an exception that is not caught it will get printed.

Comment: I just wanted to show the exception to the front-end with the custom message

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849415/how-to-stop-printing-exception-stack-trace-on-console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look to the specification of Java Exception

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

I think what you are searching for is writableStackTrace, you can set it to false if needed. Or you can override getMessage to check in with package you are or something like this. It depend on your exact needs.